# If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating' .NET Keyless attribute Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

i am working on a project in C# (.NET), and i want to make initial migration but i got a problem. i have tried so many solutions but still got error.

AppDBContext:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            object value = modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasKey(am => new
            {  
                am.ActorId,
                am.MovieId,
            }
            );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasOne(m => m.Movie).WithMany(am => am.Actors_Movies).HasForeignKey(m => m.MovieId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasOne(m => m.Actor).WithMany(am => am.Actors_Movies).HasForeignKey(m => m.ActorId);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        }
```

MovieCategory.cs:

```
namespace eTickets.Data.Enums;

public class MovieCategory
{

}
```

Error:

```
PM> add-migration initial
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'MovieCategory' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)

 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The entity type 'MovieCategory' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.
```

let me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Entity Framework, most entities have a unique identifier to reference them. The error messages Staates that your `MovieCategory` class lacks such an identifier. Either add an `Id` property to `MovieCategory`:

```
public class MovieCategory
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

If you intend to create a keyless entity, use the method described in the error message or mark the class with the `Keyless` attribute (from EF Core 5):

```
[Keyless]
public class MovieCategory
{
}
```

More information on keyless entities can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations).

Comment: Other method, also useful when EF <5, you can set the entity as modelBuilder.Entity<FooEntity>().HasNoKey();  within the override dbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)